# QFileSystemWatcher fails to get notified when /var/log/system.log changes on OSX

Tags: macos, qt, qt6, qfilesystemwatcher

After many attempts trying to keep up with the changes in OSX's `/var/log/system.log` using `QFileSystemWatcher` I am still unable to make it work.

My `QXLogWidget` class has a method to set the file path to watched:

```cpp
void QXLogWidget::setLogPath(QString logPath) {
  m_logPath = logPath;

  // Start watching changes in logPath
  m_watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher();
  m_watcher->addPath(m_logPath);

  // Connect watching events with the tail method
  connect(m_watcher, &QFileSystemWatcher::fileChanged, this, &QXLogWidget::onFileChanged);
}

···

void QXLogWidget::onFileChanged(const QString &path) {
  qDebug() << "fileChanged";
  qDebug() << path;
  readFile();
}
```

To keep it performant, `readFile` stores the file size on each call, to start from that position next time.

However, this works perfectly for a log file inside the user's home. For example, making a copy of `/var/log/system.log` to the user's home and appending lines manually with `echo "something new" >> system.log` produces the expected notifications to `QFileSystemWatcher`, which fires the connection to the `onFileChanged` event manager.

At first sight, it seems a simple issue with `/var/log/system.log` permissions but:

- Directly calling `readFile` the application reads and shows the contents of `/var/log/system.log`
- Monitoring `/var/log/system.log` with `tail -f`, we make sure it is being appended frequently.
- Permissions on `/var/log/system.log` are good enough for the sake of reading:

```
ls -Flah /var/log/system.log
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   553K 27 may 11:03 /var/log/system.log
```

- I checked `/var/log/system.log` inode does not change when new lines are being appended to it. Although I did not expect such a thing for `/var/log/system.log`, some systems rewrite log files.

So the situation is: **`QFile` can read** a system file but **`QFileSystemWatcher` is not being notified** by the OS when the file changes.

Any idea of what other condition must be relaxed here in order for `QFileSystemWatcher` to be notified?

Comment: I believe I may be seeing a similar problem. My code doesn't seem to be getting signaled when files and directories are getting removed from an external drive when their paths have been added successfully to the watcher. Sometimes my slot will get called, but only with the root path of the file system those files and directories are within and `QFileSystemWatcher::directories()` still shows the deleted directory in it.